# SDK Manager broken after Mavericks update

Tags: android, macos, android-sdk-tools, osx-mavericks

After updating my MacBook to Mavericks I recognoized that the SDK manager is no longer working correctly. When I click on the down-arrow to drop down folders content the manager has some redrawing issues (pictures)... I could live with that but its no longer possible to install new packages...

Does anyone know how to fix this?

As the SDK Manager is written in Java it should be a JRE problem(?).

[image: Android SDK Manager Window - buggy]

**[edit]**

I checked if this issue also occurs on my iMac and it does (independently). Anybody else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is with Java version 7. I'have java 7 on my OS Mavericks, and I'm seeing the same problems. I then looked into android executable (which is a bash script) and put `set -ex` on top of it. That way, I saw the exact command being run:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Commands/java -Xmx256M -XstartOnFirstThread -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir=/android/android-platform-v1-1/sdk/tools -classpath /android/android-platform-v1-1/sdk/tools/lib/sdkmanager.jar:/android/android-platform-v1-1/sdk/tools/lib/swtmenubar.jar:/android/android-platform-v1-1/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64/swt.jar com.android.sdkmanager.Main update sdk
```

So I just replaced java with version of java for 1.6.0, which in my installation, is at: `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Commands/java` and Android SDK Manager suddenly works!

See the related [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65447).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It resolved after I installed the latest JDK 7 for Mac from Oracle (7u45), available at:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Comment: Installing Java SE Development Kit 7u51 resolved this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Android emulator works fine with Java 6. You can force it to use this version by creating a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`
exec "PATH_TO_ADT_BUNDLE/sdk/tools/android" $* &>/dev/null &
```

Change `PATH_TO_ADT_BUNDLE` to where you have the `adt-bundle-mac-...` directory.

It's unfortunate it doesn't work correctly with Java 7 that has been around for a long time but you can use the workaround for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Still need help? There is a way to get this to work without modifying anything although it IS a pain in the butt.

As soon as the android SDK manager appears, you should see a bunch of changes happening on the bottom of the window (xml refreshes, etc.)...

What you want to do is quickly scroll down to the box you want checked, and click it **BEFORE** the SDK manager finishes fetching its data. You will notice that once the manager finishes refreshing itself, your box will remain checked! (if you tried checking the box after the manager fetches its data, you would not be able to check the boxes).
At this point you can click the little arrow to expand the section you checked, and from here you can further refine the specific items you want installed for that section. Of course this method implies that you may need to relaunch the SDK manager for each section you want installed.

Regarding the redrawing issue...if you scroll quickly to the bottom of the window, and then back up to where you were, you will notice that this forces the window to redraw itself (and display updated data).

-I understand this is not a true 'fix', but it **IS** a way to use the SDK manager. Hope I helped, and i'm sorry if my use of the word section made no sense lol.